# Do we need the "origin" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

[origin](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origin) has 13 posts and a tag-wiki excerpt explaining when to use it.

[etymology](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology) tag has 280 posts and a tag-wiki excerpt explaining when to use it.

Do we need the *origin* tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically, *etymology* is only about the origin of certain words, while *origin* comprises also the history of, e.g., grammatical features. However, for the latter we usually use [history](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history), though its tag-wiki excerpt is more restrictive, limiting it only to the history of words.

I thus propose to resolve this situation by:

- Synonymising [origin](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origin) to [etymology](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology).
- Retagging the few questions from [origin](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origin) that are not about etymology to [history](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history).
- Making the tag wiki for [history](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) less narrow, corresponding to its usage.